# How to avoid the code interrupting itself?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, analogread, threads

I have this code, which I am using with a potentiometer to control the speed of a automotive fuel injector. In it, I have specified how long the injector shall stay open by using the delay functions. However, whenever the code runs into a delay call, it pauses the whole code for that amount of time. Although it's not significantly long, it would still be better if it could keeping running analogInput and at the same time run through the if statements, without any interference from either. So basically run two different process simultaneously.

I remember reading somewhere that this is possible with threading? But do you need a library for that? I know Python has a threading library built in, and you can actually use it pretty easily, but what about Arduino? How could I run these two process at the same time?

Here's my code:

```
#define in1 12

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
 float rotationValue = analogRead(A1);            //read raw input from potentiometer
 float percentValue = rotationValue / 10.23;      //convert to percent 0-100
 Serial.println(percentValue);                    //print it to screen
 if(percentValue >= 0.0 && percentValue <= 1.0){
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);                         //injector 1 off
 }
 else if(percentValue > 1.0 && percentValue <= 25.00){    //cycle at 100 millisec.
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  delay(100); 
 }
 else if(percentValue > 25.00 && percentValue <= 50.00){    //cycle at 50 millis.
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  delay(50);
 }
 else if(percentValue > 50.00 && percentValue <= 75.00){      //cycle at 25 millis.
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  delay(25);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  delay(25);
 }
 else{              //cycle at 10 millis.
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  delay(10);
 }
}
```

Comment: Dump `analogRead()` and move to interrupt-based ADC operation.

Comment: What is that? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use threads on an arduino, they don't exist. you can get some pseudo multitasking going with interrupts, but that is not necessary in your case.

You should be able to refactor your code to avoid using delays without much work. The arduino library provides `millis()` to keep tract of the time since the arduino was powered on in milliseconds.

something like this could replace all the delays in your code

```
static boolean state;
static uint32_t time;
if(time < millis()){
    time += delayFromPercent(percentValue);

    state = !state;
    if(percentage < 1.0) state = false;
    digitalWrite(in1, state);
}
```

Then, somewhere else place

```
uint32_t delayFromPercent(float percent){
    if(percent < 25) return 100;
    if(percent < 50) return 50;
    if(percent < 75) return 25;
    return 10;
}
```

alternately, if you don't really want the discrete steps, you could use this instead

```
uint32_t delayFromPercent(float percent){
    return max(10, 100-percent); // don't return less than 10ms
}
```

you could change it to react a bit quicker by comparing the time plus calculated delay now rather than when it last set the pin, but that strays farther from what your initial implementation would have done.

In any case, this code will should be able to switch pin in1 without making the rest of your code slow down, as long as the other code does not use delays either.